# Error when trying to edit a file in SWI-Prolog

Tags: swi-prolog

I'm kinda new to SWI-Prolog, and I'm having some trouble installing it in my computer. I have a Mac with the new OS X, OS Sierra.

I'm trying to use it, but when I want to edit a file and use the following command:

```
edit(file('filename.pl')).
```

It returns the following:

> % Waiting for editor ...
>
> % Editor returned failure; skipped make/0 to reload files

So I'm having trouble to write code. Does anyone know what I have to do?

Comment: I think you should write: edit('filename.pl').  instead....

Comment: Do you have Xquartz installed? The SWI-Prolog tools are X11 applications.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install XQuartz (X Window System): https://www.xquartz.org/